# Polynomial roots in the ring extension

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with identity (not necessarily commutative) and $R[x]$ be a ring of polynomials over $R$. We say that a ring $S$ is an *extension* of $R$ if there is a subring $\tilde{R}$ in $S$ isomorphic to $R$.
Let $S$ be an extension of $R$, and $$\phi: R\to \tilde{R}\subset S$$
be a ring isomorphism.
We say that a polynomial $f(x) = \sum\limits_{j\geq 0}f_jx^j\in R[x]$ has a root $\alpha\in S$ if
$$
\sum\limits_{j\geq 0}\phi(f_j)\alpha^j = 0.
$$

In the case where $R$ is a commutative ring, every **monic** polynomial $f(x)\in R[x]$ has a root $[x]_f$ in the extension $S = R[x]/R[x]f(x)$ of $R$. In the case where $R$ is not commutative, the set $R[x]/R[x]f(x)$ is a left $R[x]$-module but not a ring, because the ideal $R[x]f(x)$ is not two-sided ideal, but only one-sided. Also in non-commutative case there are examples such that two-sided ideal containing $f(x)$, that is, the ideal $R[x]f(x)R[x]$, is equal to $R[x]$, and in this case $R[x]/R[x]f(x)R[x]$ is isomorphic to zero ring.

**I want to prove that for every ring with identity $R$ and every monic polynomial $f(x)$ over $R$ there exists an extension $S$ of $R$ such that $f(x)$ has a root in $S$.**

Comment: How could $R[x]f(x)R[x]$ be equal to $R[x]$ when the degree of $f$ is not 0?

Comment: @user89334 The example in my answer below does just that.  The ideal generated by $1+ax$ contains $1=(1-ax)(1+ax)$.

Comment: In general, even in the commutative case, polynomials don't have roots in an extension. Example: $f=1 + 2x\in (\mathbb{Z}/4)[x]$. The problem is that $R[x]/(f)$ is in general *no* extension of $R$.

Comment: My comment was very stupid. I came back to erase it, but figure its too late...

Comment: I am interesting only in the unitary polynomials. That is $f(x) = x^m+\sum\limits_{j= 0}^{m-1}f_jx^j$

Comment: Note: "unitary polynomial" means "monic polynomial".

Comment: @YCor thank you. But I think that we understand each other )

Comment: I know, but this was addressed to other readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a very simple and demonstrative construction of the ring extension, which came from non-commutative generalization of Hamilton-Caley's Theorem.

Let $R$ be a ring and $f(x) = x^m-\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}f_jx^j\in R[x]$ be a monic polynomial.
We identify ring $R$ with a subring $\tilde{R} = \{\mathrm{diag}(r,r,\ldots,r): r\in R\}\subset M_m(R)$.

Then $f(x)$ has a root of the form
$$
\alpha=\left(\begin{array}{llllll}
0& e& 0&\ldots& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& e&\ldots& 0& 0 \\
. & . &  . & . & .& . \\
0& 0&0&\ldots& 0& e \\
f_0& f_1& f_2&\ldots& f_{m-2}& f_{m-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is $\alpha^m-\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}f_j\alpha^j = 0\in M_m(R)$.
But we note that in general:
$f(\alpha^T)\neq 0$.

See [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303994859_Non-commutative_Hamilton-Caley%27s_Theorem_and_roots_of_characteristic_polynomials_of_skew_maximal_period_linear_recurrences_over_Galois_rings_V_International_Symposium_Current_Trends_in_Cryptography_CT) for proof  of non-commutative generalization of Hamilton-Caley's Theorem.

Comment: Nice! Note that your properties $(*)$ and $(**)$ are what Caracciolo, Sportiello and Sokal (in [arXiv:0809.3516v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3516v2)) call "column-commutativity" and "row-commutativity".

Comment: Mikhail, looking at the reference you give, the proof of the non-commutative generalization of the Caley-Hamilton theorem is done only for Galois rings (which are finite commutative rings).  Finding roots over arbitrary **commutative** rings is trivial, and doesn't need to pass through matrix rings.

Comment: I tried looking for a good source for the fact that a companion matrix of a monic polynomial satisfies that polynomial (even over a noncommutative ring).  Apparently it is just a "classical fact" that nobody has bothered to state.  The only direct reference I could find was in a paper of Andre Leroy.

Comment: @PaceNielsen, in the given refference the proof of non-commutative Hamilton-Caley Theorem is given for **arbitrary non-commutative ring with identity**.

Answer (score 7):

In the noncommutative case, your condition for a "root" is called a "right root".  I remember that T.Y. Lam worked with this condition a bit (you might search through his papers, or look in his "First Course in Noncommutative Rings" book).

It is easy to get *commutative* rings where your condition fails (because even though $R[x]f(x)$ is an ideal in $R[x]$, it still intersects $R$)!  For instance, let $F$ be a non-zero ring with identity and consider the ring

$$R=F[a\ :\ a^2=0].$$

The polynomial $f(x)=1+ax\in R[x]$ cannot have any root in any extension ring of $R$, because this would force $a$ to be a unit in the extension ring, but also nilpotent.

---

Edited to add: I've been thinking about the new question and monic polynomials.  Without loss of generality think of $R$ as contained in $S$.  If $R$ is allowed to have a different unit than $S$, I think that the answer is positive.  When $R$ is forced to be a unital subring of $S$ (i.e. containing the same unit) the answer gets a bit harder, as I'll describe below.

In the latter case, take $S:=R\coprod_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[t]/(f(t))$.  Our goal is to show that $R$ is a unital subring of $S$, and we are done.  We can do that by writing elements of $S$ in reduced form.

To explain the motivation, take $f$ to be a quadratic polynomial for a moment.  Say $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$ with $b,c\in R$.  Ignoring the "bar" notation (since $S$ is a factor ring) for convenience, we have the relation

$$t^2\mapsto -bt-c.$$

We can reduce $t^3$ in two ways, and that gives us a new relation

$$tbt\mapsto -bt-tc+ct-bc.$$

We can now reduce $t^2bt$, $tbt^2$, and $tbtbt$ in two ways (each), and we get another relation beginning $tb^2t\mapsto\cdots$.  As long as $b^n\notin \mathbb{Z}$ for each $n\geq 1$, I believe that this demonstrates that your question is positively answered (for quadratics, and this can be extended).

When $b^n\in \mathbb{Z}$ things get more complicated, but the problem may still be tractable.

When $R$ is allowed to have a different identity from $S$, there is an even easier construction.

Comment: I found the simpler example in the commutative case and beat you for 2 minutes. -:)

Comment: @Pace Nielsen, Thank you very much, but I'm interesting only in the unitary polynomials. I will clarify my question.

Comment: @Pace Nielsen, Thank you. Can you explain more  circumstantially what is the construction of $R\coprod_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[t]/(f(t))$. Also I don't understand, why $t$ don't commute with elements of $R$.

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa The elements of $R$ don't commute with $t$, because this is the coproduct of rings.  For instance the ring $\mathbb{Z}[s]\coprod_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[t] = \mathbb{Z}\langle s,t\rangle$ has $s,t$ non-commuting.  I can't explain the intricacies of the coproduct of rings in this comment, so I recommend finding a good book on the subject.